# Find minimum in rotated sorted array

Tags: python, algorithm

The given code find the minimum element in a sorted array rotated by some fixed distance.
Eg: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] -> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2]`

The elements in the array are all unique. Just wanted to check if the code handles all edge cases and is correct.

```
def findMin(ary):

    def recurse(lo, hi):
        # Base cases   
        if (ary[lo] < ary[hi]):
            return ary[lo]
        if (hi - lo == 1):
            return min(ary)

        mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2
        if (ary[mid] < ary[hi]):
            return recurse(lo, mid)
        else:
            return recurse(mid, hi)

    return recurse(0, len(ary) - 1)


ary = (3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2)
print findMin(ary) # 1
```

Comment: Some explanation of the problem and what you'd like to get from the reviews would be nice.

Comment: I believe this approach doesn't work if there are repeated entries in the array.

Comment: I belive you wanted to return ary[hi] if (hi - lo == 1), right?

Comment: @BartekKobyłecki, I first solve the problem in notebook (since I don't have white board :)) so after trying couple of cases I found that when there are only two elements left then the minimum is within those two elements. For example in the above problem I was left with `[7, 1]`. I hope I am right.

Comment: @Jaime, yes already written in the problem description above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Why are you giving up?**

```
if (hi - lo == 1):
    return min(ary)
```

So we're almost done with our nice `O(lg N)` algorithm, when suddenly... we start over and do a whole new `O(N)` search from scratch throwing everything away? Why? Let's examine such a scenario:

```
ary = [3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2]

lo = 0, hi = 6, mid = 3
ary[mid] (6) > ary[hi] (2), so recurse mid to hi

lo = 3, hi = 6, mid = 4
ary[mid] (0) < ary[hi] (2), so recurse lo to mid

lo = 3, hi = 4
hi - lo == 1, so return min(ary) == 0
```

At this point, we have `ary[lo] == 6` and `ary[hi] == 0`. We know one of those two is the minimum, and we know which one that is. So let's use that information:

```
def recurse(lo, hi):
    # Base cases   
    if (ary[lo] < ary[hi]):
        return ary[lo]
    elif (hi - lo == 1):
        return ary[hi] ## just return a number, don't call min()
    else:
        mid = ...
        # rest as before
```

Comment: I thought about this case but wasn't sure that this case `[0, 1]` will not arise but I was sure that at the end there will be always two elements left. Also, if there are only two elements then what's the issue of calling `min` on it? thanks,

Comment: @CodeYogi, ary is always the reference of the full array.`min(ary)` is calculating minimum from full array, not two just elements that left. Insted you could code it like: `min([ary[lo], ary[hi]])` but as Barry described you know which of these two elements is smaller.

Comment: @Barry, ah it makes me feels so idiot. Maybe I need to practice a lot and continue to ask stuffs here. Thanks!